# xml encoding registers as string in php page

Tags: php, xml

I have a .php page with a javascript function that loads XML data to print a barcode, however when I define my XML, the

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
```

registers as a string for some reason. In an HTML page it works fine but im assuming the opening ? is causing an issue with php. Any suggestions, or a workaround for this?

```
  var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
            <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
            <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
            <Id>Address</Id>\
            <PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
            <DrawCommands>\
            <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270"/>\
            </DrawCommands>\
            <ObjectInfo>\
            <BarcodeObject>\
            <Name>BARCODE</Name>\
            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/>\
            <BackColor Alpha="255" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255"/>\
            <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
            <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
            <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
            <IsVariable>False</IsVariable>\
            <Text>*E200001*</Text>\
            <Type>Code39</Type>\
            <Size>Medium</Size>\
            <TextPosition>Bottom</TextPosition>\
            <TextFont Family="Lucida Grande" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>\
            <CheckSumFont Family="Lucida Grande" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>\
            <TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding>\
            <ECLevel>0</ECLevel>\
            <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
            <QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Right="0" Top="0" Bottom="0"/>\
            </BarcodeObject>\
            <Bounds X="331.2" Y="328.0469" Width="4455.625" Height="1044.844"/>\
            </ObjectInfo>\
            </DieCutLabel>';
```

Comment: You have to run `header("Content-Type:text/xml");` or else the browser won't know you're sending it xml.  If that doesn't work, I might also try looking at the `?>` in the string, as that always confuses PHP.  Try `'?'.'>'` or something along those lines.

Comment: Ok it seems to work fine without the ?> and just >.